# Google Chrome displays "Aw Snap" screen too often

Tags: php, mysql, google-chrome

I have been working on developing a Social Networking application based on LAMP. I put the website on a free web hosting solution. But visiting it sometimes takes me to the Google Chrome "Aw Snap! Something Went wrong" page. However, it works fine on all other browsers. The error comes in too often when visiting the website, and sometimes when visiting it over localhost. What may possibly be the reason for this?

I suspect it's due to Running two SSE(server sent events) in the background simultaneously.

Possibly because the SSEs develop a large amount of data as time passes(because the error displays often only when a link is clicked a little while after the SSE starts sending data, and not on the first go.).

I kept an eye on the Google Chrome's developer console. On clicking a link, it displays the error: "Failed to load resource onlineStudents.php" and "Failed to load resource checkMessages.php".

The scripts for the same are:

chat.php

```
<script>
if(typeof(EventSource)!=="undefined")
  { 
     var source2=new EventSource("onlineStudents.php");
     source2.onmessage=function(event2)
     {
        var data=JSON.parse(event2.data);
        $("#chat_head_number").html(": "+data['total']);
        for(var i=1;i<30;i++)
        {
            $("#chat_states_number"+i).html(" ");
            x=$("#state"+i).text();
            for( var j=0;j<data['statesName'].length;j++)
            {
                 if(data['statesName'][j]==x)
                 {
                     $("#chat_states_number"+i).html(" : "+data['statesNumber'][j]);
                 }
            }
        }
      }
    }
 </script>
```

onlineStudents.php

```
<?php session_start();
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
require_once 'myfunctions.php';
$query="Select * from online_students where email<>'$_SESSION[user]'";
$result=  queryMysql($query);
$data["total"]=mysql_num_rows($result);
$query="Select distinct state from online_students";
$result=queryMysql($query);
while($row=  mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $query2="select * from online_students where state='$row[state]' and email<>'$_SESSION[user]'";
    $result2=queryMysql($query2);
    $data["statesName"][]=$row['state'];
    $data["statesNumber"][]=mysql_num_rows($result2);
}
$query="Select distinct college from online_students";
$result=  queryMysql($query);
while($row=  mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $query2="Select * from online_students where college='$row[college]' and email<>'$_SESSION[user]'";
    $result2=queryMysql($query2);
    $data["collegesName"][]=$row['college'];
    $data["collegesNumber"][]=mysql_num_rows($result2);
}
echo "data:".json_encode($data)."\n\n";
ob_flush();
flush();
sleep(3);
?>
```

header.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(typeof(EventSource)!=="undefined")
{
  var source=new EventSource("checkMessages.php");
  source.onmessage=function(event)
  {
      $("#new_message").html("Inbox"+event.data);
  };
 }
else
{
  $("#new_message").html("HTML5 not supported");
} 
</script>
```

checkMessages.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'myfunctions.php';
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
$userid=studentidOf($_SESSION['user']);
$query="Select distinct msgby from messages where msgfor='$userid'";
$result=queryMysql($query);
$k=mysql_num_rows($result);
$query="Select postnumber from notifications where notifor=$userid and postnumber is NOT NULL";
$result=queryMysql($query);
$k+=mysql_num_rows($result);
$collegeid=collegeidOf($_SESSION['user']);
$query="Select collegeid_post from notifications where notifor=$userid and      collegeid_post=$collegeid and notiby<>$userid";
$result=queryMysql($query);
$k+=mysql_num_rows($result);
$query="Select collegeid_forum from notifications where notifor=$userid and collegeid_forum=$collegeid and notiby<>$userid";
$result=queryMysql($query);
$k+=mysql_num_rows($result);
$query="Select threadid from notifications where notifor=$userid and threadid is NOT NULL";
$result=queryMysql($query);
$k+=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($k>0)
  echo "data:($k)\n\n";
ob_flush();
flush();
?>
```

Comment: Do your server logs give you any input? You mentioned free hosting, so maybe you don't have access to those. Perhaps the lesson here is you get what you pay for. If free... then this is no surprise at all

Comment: Is this only happening in Chrome? Does your site run fine in other browsers?

Comment: @KaiQing - Yes I mentiones free hosting, but I also mentioned testing it over my local server : localhost. It's the same in both cases with Google Chrome.

Comment: @j08691 - yes, it runs fine in other browsers, except that the webpage very rarely stops loading in Mozilla Firefox, after half the page has been loaded. But this happens only over webhost, and not my localhost.

Comment: It could possibly be taking too long to respond and chrome cancels the request. Have you set your php's max execution time: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php - this is not a solution. Just something that can extend the default 30 second limits. Do your local logs give any insight

Comment: @KaiQing - but the error page displays as soon as I click on the web link. It does not take any time to respond. I could not figure anything out with FIDDLER logs.

Comment: You should put that in the question. That's an interesting detail. Like it's temporarily not resolving. Typically chrome will give a better report than aw snap, like if there's a redirect loop or something. Does this happen no matter what page you're on? Or any other lead that can help isolate the event

Comment: @KaiQing - I had a big time googling the problem. Perhaps, could you help visting the link and see what's the source of problem? I'd be grateful to you.

Comment: No, there's this default.php which loads perfectly well. But whenever I click on any link contained in that page, the error message appears almost instantly in all the tabs containing pages from my website.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the site?

Comment: Okay, the link is uitadda.hostei.com You'll need a user login and password. Enter dummy@dummy.com for username, and notadummy for password and log in. Then comes the default.php page. Click on the Dummy Dummy displayed at the top in the navigation bar, that's where the error fires up.

Comment: I checked and clicked around for a while. I never got an error. Can you check another PC?

Comment: I didn't personally check on other PCs, but my users have been repeatedly reporting me of the same. Its just not too good an answer to suggest them using Mozilla Firefox or other browsers instead of Google Chrome. What generally causes this type of error page to come up? Any one of my suspected reasons that I mentioned in the question?

Comment: @KaiQing - did you try the Logout link on the navbar? Clcking it takes to the Error page!

Comment: I did. it logged me out as expected

Comment: please check out two more probable reasons I added onto the question.

Comment: i have edited the question. Please check it

Comment: Yes, the error is due to the Server Sent Events. I tried removing the SSEs, and it works amazingly fine, and faster. Why does it happen? What can I do to make the SSEs work alright.

Comment: `sleep(3)` in **onlineStudents.php** was the cause of problem. I removed it, now it works fine.